# Prove (15n+17,10n+11) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I am new to number theory and wanted to know If I am doing this correctly:

W.t.s. $(15n+17,10n+11) = 1$

Using the Division Algorithm we have

$15n + 17 = (10n + 11)(1) + (5n + 6)$

$10n + 11 = (5n + 6)(1) + (5n + 5)$

$5n + 6 = (5n + 5) + 1$

$\Rightarrow$ $(15n + 17,10n + 11)$ = ($5n + 5,1)$, but $(5n + 5,1)$ = $1$ (1 is relatively prime to every integer)

$\therefore$ $(15n+17,10n+11) = 1$ as needed?

Comment: How did you get $(5n+5)=1$?

Comment: @AlexS He is using the euclidean algorithm and I assume he meant $(5n+5,1)=1$. Other than that it looks correct to me.

Comment: @AlexS lol yeah I meant $(5n+5,1) = 1$ , division algorithm.

Comment: @CyclotomicFieldAwesome thanks!! yeah that was a typo lol

Comment: @Hossien Sahebjame That's what I thought, but wanted to be sure. And yes, your solution is correct, because the algorithm halts and returns a value of 1.

Comment: @AlexS Awesome! thought that too, wanted to make sure. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eliminate $n$

$$2(15n+17)-3(10n+11)=?$$

Comment: Im confused how do I use this to show it holds $\forall n$? Isn't this just one particular ($x_0,y_0)$ satisfying the diophantine equation since we know it is solvable? ($a = 15n + 17$ and $b = 10n + 11$)

Comment: @Hossien Sahebjame The g.c.d. of a and b is a $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combination of $a$ and $b$. The value of $n$ is eliminated regardless of the choice of its value ($2*15n-3*10n=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$).